# Таблица падежей

Tags: грамматика, падежи

Как быстро запомнить таблицу падежей? Как научиться отличать винительный падеж от родительного?

Answer (score 1):

1) **Порядок падежей** (И, Р, Д, В, Т, П) можно запомнить так: Иван рубит дрова, Варвара топит печь.

2) **Вопросы запоминаются в сочетаниях:** И. п. (что?) река, (кто?) друг, Р.п. (нет чего?) реки, (кого?) друга,  Д.п. (рад чему?) реке, (кому?) другу, В.п. вижу (что?) реку, (кого?) друга, Т.п. любуюсь (чем?) рекой, (кем?) другом, П.п. (думаю о чём?) о реке, (о ком?) о друге.

3) **Винительный и родительный падежи могут отвечать на одинаковый вопрос "кого?"**, если они выражают одушевленность предмета.

а) **Для одушевленных существительных форма В.п. совпадает с  формой Р.п**.: нет (кого?) мальчика, мальчиков и девочек, вижу (кого? мальчика, мальчиков и девочек.

б) **Для неодушевленных существительных форма В.п. совпадает с  формой И.п**.:  (что?) стол, столы, вижу (что?) стол, столы.

4) **Значение одушевленности/неодушевленности выражают только сущ. м.р. ед. чила и сущ. мн. числа,** поэтому для различения Р.п. и В.п. можно использовать сущ. ж. рода, например:

спроси (у кого?) у мальчик**а** и  девочк**и** - Р.п.; расскажи  (про кого?) про мальчик**а** и девочк**у** (В.п.).

Мы видим, что с**ущ. ж.р. в ед.ч.**, в том числе одушевленные, не имеют одинаковых окончаний и всегда **ясно выражают падеж**: девочка - нет девочки (Р.п.), вижу девочку (В.п.).